# Inserting a record from Linux PHP site to Windows SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, windows

I'm attempting to manipulate a database on a Windows SQL Server from a Linux hosted PHP based site, but I'm having problems even connecting to it.

```
$host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:1433';
$user = 'user';
$password = "secretpassword";
$db_name = "DB_TO_SELECT";

//Connect to DB - this is where the error happens:   Login failed for user 'user'
$handle = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot connect to server. " .      mssql_get_last_message());

//Select the DB
$db = mssql_select_db($db_name, $handle) or die("Cannot find database.");

//query
$query = "INSERT INTO Records (FirstName) VALUES ('Test')";

//execute
$result = mssql_query($query);

mssql_close($handle);
```

It appears to succesfully select the named instance 'SQLEXPRESS' by specifying the port. But I'm wondering if the username isn't in the right format.

If I add "SQLEXPRESS\" before the username, I get the error:

```
Cannot connect to server. Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

But it does this if I include any named instance before the username.

Can anyone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong ?

EDIT - I will note I have triple checked, and the password I'm using in the code is correct.

Comment: Try connecting to host `'xx.xx.xx.xx\\SQLEXPRESS'`

Comment: When I do that, it times out and I just get the message "Cannot connect to server" and nothing is in mssql_get_last_message()

Comment: Oh my god, I was using $pass instead of $password on the mssql_connect function. Wow.